# Using methods with "@Named" annotation in its parameters

Tags: java, jpa

I am working with JPA and i have a method

```
/**
 * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
 *
 * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
 * @return The entity with primary key id.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "getNote")
public Note getNote(@Named("id") String id) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    Note note = null;
    try {
        note = mgr.find(Note.class, id);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return note;
}
```

but am not sure how to use this method.I have read a lot of tutorials on this but am still confused.
I tried using it like this

```
Note newResult = endpoint.getNote(noteID).execute();
```

but it returns `Null`.

Comment: Well, find() returns null if the entity with the given ID doesn't exist. That's why you get null.

Comment: But am i trying to get the entity the right way? Am trying to understand the meaning of `getNote(@named("id") String id)` and if i am passing the parameter the right way with `endpoint.getNote(noteID)`.
NoteID contains the id of the entity.

Comment: The annotations here have nothing to do with Hibernate/JPA. They're used by some other framework. Annotations, anyway, don't change anything to how you call a method. they're just metadata that can be used by some framework.

Comment: Okay.why then is it returning null? I seem to be doing everything right

Comment: It's returning null because there is no row in the table having the ID you're passing as argument.

Comment: But there is an Entity with the ID..It's right there in the datastore.

Comment: Add debugging to check that the passed in 'id' string is what you think it is, what the mgr.find() is returning, and turn on JPA logging in your provider to check that it is hitting the database you think it should, with the query and ID values you think it should.  There are other reasons, such as maybe your entity with that ID is not yet committed in a different context to the one you are calling find on.  Too many possibilities without more information.

Comment: How is the primary key defined? Could you paste some code? Maybe it's `int`, thus passing `String` to `mgr.find()` leads to an exception and `finally` block is executed? Or the primary key is of `String` type, but your database does not allow to use `String` as ID?

Comment: The primary key is also a property.It was defined as `@Id String username` and yes,Google App engine does allow Strings as id